# Unable to load dynamic library in a .NET app on Linux

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio-mac, dynamic-library

Unable to load dynamic library on Linux

- I built a project on Mac OS and the output was a `libmylibrary.so` and `libmylibrary.dylib` files.
- I copied the `.dylib` into a Visual Studio Console project and was able to load and invoke the functions of the library using the `DllImport` function. The project works as expected
- I copied the project (including the `.so` and `.dylib` files) into a Ubuntu-based Docker container
- When I run the project using `dotnet run`, I get the below error

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'mylibrary' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libmylibrary, 1): image not found
```

---

**Edit 1**

 Below is the Dockerfile used to create the container

```
FROM streetcred/dotnet-indy AS base
WORKDIR /app

# Expose the default port
EXPOSE 5000

COPY SomeProject/ ./

RUN dotnet restore "SomeProject.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "SomeProject.csproj" -c Release -o build
RUN dotnet publish "SomeProject.csproj" -c Release -o build
RUN COPY libmylibrary.dylib build/libmylibrary.dylib
RUN COPY libmylibrary.so build/libmylibrary.so
CMD dotnet build/SomeProject.dll --urls http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

---

**Edit 2**

 I tried the following, **but I get the same error**

- Compile the `mylibrary` project in a Linux Docker Container (Ubuntu)
- Copy the generated `mylibrary.so` file in the `SomeProject`

---

**Edit 3**

 Based on @paladin324 comments, I tried the following, **but I get the same error**

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/SomeProject/build
cd /app/SomeProject/build
dotnet SomeProject.dll --urls http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

Comment: What does your Dockerfile look like?

Comment: @MattThalman, added the Dockerfile in the description

Comment: MacOS isn't Linux (it's derived from FreeBSD, a Unix variant) . The services and APIs are different. `.dylib` is the extension for MacOS dynamic libraries and won't work in any Linux distribution. You'll have to recompile `mylibrary` for Linux

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, tried your suggestion. Getting the same error. Please refer to the `Edit 2` section in the description

Comment: Is `mylib.so` a native (C++) library? .NET libraries are always named `.dll`, regardless of the OS.

Comment: @PMF, this is the library that I'm trying to build. It generates the libs of `.dylib` and `.so`

https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/tree/master/experimental/plugins/postgres_storage

Comment: I guess then you didn't really recompile for linux. A linux build does not give a dylib file (that's macOS-specific). Linux libraries are .so only. `file myLibrary.so` should say something like ` ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked,`

Comment: @PMF, I built the library in a Linux (Ubuntu) Container. It generated `.so`, `.a`, and a few other files. However, I get the same error with the `.so` file

Comment: How does your `DllImport` directive look like?

Comment: @PMF, 

`[DllImport("myLibrary", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]`

Comment: Could you try prepending `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/app/build` to `dotnet build/SomeProject.dll` to make absolutely sure that `dlopen` will search the right directory? I have a feeling that `build/` might not get searched because the CWD of the process is `/app`, not `/app/build`, so this would be a good way to ensure that.

Comment: @paladin324, I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Please read the section `Edit 3` of the description.

Comment: @SahilKhanna To pass the variable in the command environment, you need to prefix the command line with the variable assignment. Could you try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/SomeProject/build dotnet SomeProject.dll --urls http://0.0.0.0:5000` (as a single command)?

Comment: @paladin324, tried your suggestion.  Getting the error `System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'mylibrary' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libmylibrary: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

.NET uses the platform's naming conventions.
`DllImport("myLibrary")` is going to look for a file named `libmylibrary.so` (the original filename of the binary).
Try changing:

```
RUN COPY mylibrary.so build/mylibrary.so
```

to

```
RUN COPY mylibrary.so build/umylibrary.so
```

Comment: I have corrected the `RUN COPY` command in the `Edit 1` section of the description. I have the files `mylibrary.so`, `umylibrary.so` and `libmylibrary.so` in the build folder. However, I'm getting the same error